# Pushing 2 different folder into a same repo on Github

Tags: git, github

I am fairly new to github as a whole, so there are some explaination or words that are not quite clear, I am sorry.

I used to have a folder called "statictis" that is link with a github repo called "statictis code files". The original folder which contains the original files that is linked to the original github is now **gone** on my local machine.

Recently, I have created some code files that are related to the "statictis code files" repo that I have on github, but because I don't have the original folder that is linked to the repo (I deleted it). I am trying to find a way to push my new code to the old repo but because the original folder that is linked to the repo is now gone, I am stuck, I tried to add it the usual way:

```
git init
git remote add origin <remote link>
git add .
git commit -m 'New edit date/time'
git push origin master
```

And I received this error:

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to '*github repo link*'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

And I have tried to pull by using the pull command:

```
git pull <remote> master:dev
git push origin master
```

But I receive a new error saying that my brach was behind. So I saw a suggestion saying using push -f, but this will delete my commit.

If you have any suggestion mention. Instruction would be much appreciate.

**TL;DR:**

-The folder that is linked to my github repo on my local machine is now deleted.

-I have some files in a totally different new folder that are related to the subject of the repo and I am trying to push it to the old github repo but it keep displaying errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you created a repo and accidentally lost the files in your local or in github? If you've lost the files on your local, you could just clone the project again from the repo to your local.

```
git clone https://github.com/github/training-kit.git
```

Alternately, if some of your changes in your local is present and you only deleted a couple of folders, you could revert the changes you made.

`git checkout .` or `git restore .` will revert all your local uncommitted changes.

Then make changes code_2 and push it back to the repo. Let me know if this understanding is correct or modify your question and I can update my answer too :)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, this was not the answer that I was anticipated, I have since edit my question to hopfully further explain my problem. Thank you again.

Comment: The simplest way to get back your changes is to clone the repo from github to your local again. You will get back all your lost folders or files. Just delete the whole folder. Use that `git clone` command to setup and get back your folder and files and make new changes as needed. The reason you see errors is because git remote has the files and you seem to push different updates that conflict with those in your local without having remote's changes. You need to ensure you have actual changes from remote before making further updates,

Comment: So, I need to clone all the folders from my old repo, add the new files and push them back up again correct?

Comment: `git clone repo` command will clone the whole project from remote to local. So you will get all folders that you see in github. For more info on git clone you can check here [link](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository/git-clone#:~:text=Usage,copies%20an%20existing%20Git%20repository). Then you make your changes and push. :)

Comment: Thank you, it worked, it pushed the new files while also keep the old commits. But are there alternative ways? Because to clone is to download your files from the repo, imagine hundred of files, would clonning it takes alot of times? @Arjun

Comment: I have projects with 2000+ files. Cloning still takes less than 30 seconds.  :)